# Unable to access Qnap NAS device

Tags: networking, switch, network-attached-storage, qnap

I have a Qnap NAS connected to Qnap QSW-M2108-2C managed switch. That switch has one port leading to the internet and another port connected to a MacBook running Qfinder Pro. Everything was working fine and I was able to connect to the NAS successfully over the network. However, after relocating all of the above gear to a new location I have not been able to successfully connect and I cannot figure out what is the problem. All of the devices seem to be acquiring new IP addresses over DHCP and on an initial scan Qfinder sees the NAS. But there is an orange exclamation point in the status column and attempts to connect fail followed by the NAS disappearing from Qfinder on subsequent scans.

I've included some screen shots to illustrate the problem. Can someone point me to the solution? I've tried rebooting the switch and using a different MacBook. I have not rebooted the NAS for the simple reason that I cannot connect to it to shut it down safely. I do not want to risk my data with a hard reboot.

[image]

[image]

EDIT - I've also just tried the following but the problem persists

- Rebooted using the button on the front of the 653D NAS. Apparently you can do a safe shutdown by holding the button for three seconds. This is not documented in the official manual but is mentioned by users on the Qnap forums.
- Reset the NAS settings by holding the reset button for three seconds

Comment: You need to describe your network configuration - subnets, IP addresses assigned to devices, routing configuration etc. Otherwise, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what information to provide, but IP addresses for the NAS and switch are shown in the screenshot. The laptop receives 172.6.5.50 when I hardwire it to the switch. I have not created an subnets. The switch is also connected to a hotel ethernet port, which presumably leads to a router.

Comment: Additionally, we'll need to see the switch configuration. Have you checked whether the switch shows the NAS's MAC address in the correct VLAN?

Comment: Change the cable maybe? Hard to guess without enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if you relocate your gear often and you are "guest" on someone's else network (The switch is also connected to a hotel ethernet port...) you should create your own subnet even with a cheap router to be put between your subnet (switch, nas and macbook) ant the external network. This way you control what's happening inside and you mask your devices from the outside, other than aving the possibility to troubleshoot more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated -- it's very likely a network configuration issue. More specifically -- it's like the hotel network you're connect to doesn't allow devices on it's LAN to communicate with one another. This is very common. Considering you're using DHCP assignments from the Hotel's DHCP server, it is also safe to assume you're not using any internal routes between your wired devices.